# While trying to start Celery, I am faced with incompatible demands from celery and flask while importing modules. What do I do?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to start Celery in a Flask app. My goal is to run the Flask app with Celery accepting workers simultaneously. To do this, I need to figure out how to satisfy the demands of both Celery and Flask.

To run Celery, I run: `celery -A rentCanada worker --loglevel=debug`

and I get the wall of beautiful blue text telling me its running.

But then I try to run Flask: `flask run` and I get:

```
  File "/home/rlm/Code/canadaAps/rentCanada.py", line 5, in <module>
    from config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

So it's like, "ok, I will fix the import ..."

`from config import Config` <= how it is when Celery works, but Flask doesn't. Code is from `rentCanada.py`

My folder is like this

```
/rootDir
  __init__.py
  rentCanada.py <= flask entry point, 
  config.py <= this is trying to be imported
  /scrapers
     __init__.py
     Scraper.py
  /blueprints
     __init__.py  # and more files
  /api
     __init__.py # and more files
  /util
     __init__.py # and more files
```

It now reads: `from .config import Config` and flask now gives me new errors:

```
  File "/home/rlm/Code/canadaAps/rentCanada.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapers.Scraper import Scraper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapers'
```

It's like, ok, I'll fix those:

in `/scrapers/Scraper`: `from util.proxyTools import ProxyTools` becomes `from ..util.proxyTools import ProxyTools` or else I get an error.

This is enough to demostrate that I have a lose-lose situation with Celery. I run the Celery start cmd from before and I get:

```
  File "/home/rlm/Code/canadaAps/rentCanada.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .config import Config
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I start Celery in the `rentCanada.py` file:

```
celery = Celery("rentCanada", broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL, result_backend=Config.RESULT_BACKEND)

application = create_app(celery)
```

I think most if not all of the issue is that I really don't understand Python 3.11's importing system. There's this thing with `__init__.py` that I have to do. I am elite at JavaScript imports compared to this.

My goal is to run "flask run" and the celery command at the same time. I know this is possible but I am not good enough at Python, Flask and Celery to solve it on my own.

What confuses me is that both the Flask app and Celery are initiated from the same file. Hence I expect the imports setup to work for both.

Answer (score 1):

someone on Discord fixed it for me. The solution was to put all my python code in a directory named after my root directory, and then run celery like `celery -A canadaAps.rentCanada worker --loglevel=debug` when the entrypoint file is now in a directory like

```
/canadaAps
    /canadaAps
         rentCanada.py
```

now everything is in a module.